# Typing an Optional staticmethod with and without arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to add typing for a method that is None (has the literal value of None) in the base class, but child classes can implement it using a staticmethod. What I have so far is as followed:

```py
class BaseClass:
    attr: ClassVar[Optional[Callable[[str], None]]] = None


class ChildClass1(BaseClass):
    pass


class ChildClass2(BaseClass):
    @staticmethod
    def attr(s: str):
        return "hello"
```

This is what I expected to work, but instead mypy is throwing:

```
test.py:14: error: Signature of "attr" incompatible with supertype "BaseClass"  [override]
```

Interestingly, if the function doesn't have arguments, it works:

```py
class BaseClass:
    attr: ClassVar[Optional[Callable[[], None]]] = None


class ChildClass2(BaseClass):
    @staticmethod
    def attr():
        return "hello"
```

Answer (score 2):

A pretty easy workaround is to define the method under a different name and then assign the attr to it:

```
from typing import ClassVar, Callable, Optional

class BaseClass:
    attr: ClassVar[Optional[Callable[[str], str]]] = None


class ChildClass1(BaseClass):
    pass


class ChildClass2(BaseClass):
    @staticmethod
    def _attr(s: str) -> str:
        return "hello"
    attr = _attr
```

My guess is that mypy just has a minor bug where it doesn't handle this particular edge case of an attr that's only defined as a method in some implementations.  I've never seen this pattern before -- it seems like it defeats the purpose of defining a base interface, but maybe seeing the real-world use case would make it make more sense to me.

Comment: My real-world case is that I'm trying to define something akin to Django's Meta, but in my case - to define a retention policy for the database data. I want all models that define one (class RetentionPolicy(RetentionPolicyBase)) to inherit from the base class and get None as the value for a bunch of attributes. This way I can
1. More easily ensure the correct types and 2. Save myself a bunch of getattr calls.

And while I appreciate the suggestion, having every model that defines a retention policy to use this workaround isn't great. If it's a mypy bug, I'd rather open an issue there.